# How to trim an encoded String?

Tags: java, string, encoding, trim

I'm using following code :

```
searchKey = URLEncoder.encode(searchKey,"UTF-8");
builder.queryParam("searchKey", searchKey.trim());
```

Now, I've tried :

```
String s = "hello%20world%20%26%20you%20%20%20%20%20%20";
s.trim();
System.out.println(s);
```

Output :

```
hello%20world%20%26%20you%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

What could be a possible workaround?

Note: I also thought of trimming my searchKey before encoding, but it is already encoded as recieved from some other restcall which uses some other encoding.

Comment: For starters, `s.trim();` doesn't update `s`.

Comment: But then, trimming an encoded string won't trim `%20`s. Decode it, trim it, re-encode it.

Comment: @AndyTurner (decode - trim - encode) would work fine. Thanks. Just wondering if there is any fashionable way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does trim() method of String class work with encoded string?

No, for the simple reason that Java has no way to distinguish an encoded string from a string which just happens to include encoded character sequences. URL encoding is merely one amongst an infinite number of encodings, and it would be unfeasible to try to work out if the string is a value encoded in any particular one.

If you want to trim an encoded string, you have to decode it first, *then* trim it, then re-encode it.

---

Note however that `s.trim();` doesn't update `s`. Strings are immutable. You would need to assign `s = s.trim();`, or similar.

Comment: (decode - trim - encode) would work fine. Thanks.
Just wondering if there is any fashionable way to this?

Answer (score -2):

Use `s.trim();`and store it in a new variable and then use that new variable. It should get working.